# How to write view to update model image in django?

Tags: python, django, admin

I extend the django User model with a profile model. I want add update user's profile function. Because I make the `num` field a unique field, in my update view function, the update form's `is_valid` was always `False`. I also cannot update the photo png? Here is my code;

Models:

```
class Profile(models.model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   num =models.CharField('identity',max_length=254,unique=True)
   photo = models.ImageField('image',upload_to = 'images/licences')
```

forms:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= Profile
        fields = ['num','photo']
```

views:

```
def modify_view(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid() 
            user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
            user_profile.image = form.clean_data['image']
            user_profile.save()
    else:
        form = ProfileForm()
        return render(request,"profile.html",{form:form})
```

template

```
{% extends  'account/home/index.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-8">

      <form class="signup needs-validation" id="signup_form" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        {% if redirect_field_value %}
        <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
        {% endif %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <button  type="submit" class="col-sm-8  offset-sm-4 btn btn-success btn-block">update</button> 
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: If `form.is_valid()` is `False`, what is in `form.errors` after you validate it?

Comment: "The num field has been existed." I know that I set this num the unique, and I update only change the image, so this error will happen.

Comment: Isn't it `request.FILES` (upper case)?

Comment: @art06   yes, it's my faults. I fixed it. But the form.isvalid() is still False.

Comment: If you just want to update the image, dont initialize the `ProfileForm` class with `request.POST`

Comment: @SachinKukreja ok, I'll try it. It's not necessary to check the form.is_vali().

Comment: Please post the form template.

Comment: @art06 I added it. It is a simple form template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `num` field is unique and will not be generated again on updating the profile image, you can ignore `request.POST` and pass the `instance` argument to the `ProfileForm` class.

**Example**:

```
def modify_view(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method=="POST":
        user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)

        form = ProfileForm(files=request.FILES, instance=user_profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            user_profile.image = form.clean_data['image']
            user_profile.save()
    else:
        form = ProfileForm()
    return render(request,"profile.html",{form:form}
```